# How to push to a new folder in existing git repo

Tags: git, github

I have an existing github repo with code in. I also have a another codebase locally, without a common commit ancestor to that github repo. I want to push that local codebase to my remote repo, on the main branch, in a new folder say /project2 so that its neatly seperate from the existing code in the remote repo.

I have done `git init` on my local codebase, `git add .` and `git commit` and also set the remote repo to my github url. All good. I'm just stuck on how I tell git to push to a new folder so that this local code is seperate (organisationally) to the existing code in the remote repo.

How do I do that?

Comment: You want to merge 2 different repos or what?

Comment: no, just keep them in seperate folders. No merging. They are totally seperate code bases, but part of the same overall project hence no merge but I want to keep them organisationally together in the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that everything in your local codebase is inside a folder *project2*. Make sure you are on main. Then:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main --allow
git push origin @
```

Comment: should my .git and .gitignore file be inside the project2 folder or not?

Comment: No, the project2 folder is inside the project.